# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo getting old version of an exe swapped at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a program executing in c# that is sometimes updated while it is running by swapping the exe to a new one. I want the program to routinely check if it has been updated and if so, restart. I use the following function to do this.

```
    public static bool DoINeedToRestart(string exe_name)
    {

        Version cur_version = new Version(MainProgram.StartVersion);
        Version file_version = new Version(GetProductVersion(exe_name));
        MessageBox.Show("Comparing cur_version " + cur_version.ToString() + " with " + file_version.ToString());
        if (file_version > cur_version)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static string GetProductVersion(string path_name)
    {
            FileVersionInfo myFI = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path_name);
            return myFI.FileVersion;
    }
```

MainProgram.StartVersion is set when the program is started to be the current version using the GetProductVersion(exe_name)

exe_name is set to be the name of the executable that is being updated.

The problem I have is once the MainProgram.exe file has been updated (I verify this manually by looking at the file properties and checking the file version), the GetProductVersion still returns the old file version and I have no idea why! Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm running Windows Vista with .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system?  If this is Windows, then I'm afraid you're mistaken about swapping a .exe file that's executing -- all running programs are locked by the virtual memory manager in the Windows kernel.  It's entirely possible that you have some .NET library doing redirection behind the scenes to make it look as if the new file is in place, but only file access through that library will be affected.

EDIT: As far as I know, Windows resists attempts to delete or rename not only the executable which is mapped into memory, but also all parent directories.  Since you're on Vista, it is actually possible you are seeing the effects of a façade -- for non-administrator programs, Windows redirects writes and later reads of the Windows and Program Files directories into a per-user virtual area.  If you're starting the program through any non-elevated means, you might actually be running a copy of the app in the virtual area.  The Installer service (MSIEXEC) runs with fully-elevated admin rights, so it is immune to the redirection.  So I posit that Windows Installer overwrites the version in C:\Program Files\whatever, while your app sees the version from the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\whatever overlay, which is unchanged.  Normally if the version in the "real" directory changes, it will have a newer modification time than the overlay version, so the "real" version would be used.  But if the install process is preserving the modification time, then it is possible that the overlay has the more recent time and continues to be used.

Comment: Hi Ben. It's running on Windows Vista (.NET 3.5). I understand the program loaded in the kernel can't be swapped, but it certainly looks as though the .exe on the file system can be. I seem to be able to delete it or rename it without effecting the running of the program. Does this mean the running program would still see it as being there even after I have removed it?

Comment: Apologies Ben but I need to correct myself. I can rename the .exe of a running process but can't delete them - I retested this a few times. The Windows Installer is what is updating the file and that seems to be able to delete the old version and put the new one in (when viewed through explorer). As you say, this could be a façade.

Comment: That's interesting.  How are you starting the program, and what is the path?  I'm adding additional information to my answer as it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Also, I reflected on `FileVersionInfo` and there doesn't appear to be any caching going on in the .NET wrapper code.  Neither does the native API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003(VS.85).aspx mention any caching.  However, there is some magic going on if there are mui (multi-lingual user interface) files present.

Comment: Thanks Ben. The application starts as normal under the account of the user who calls the exe. There is a partner service running as SYSTEM that checks for a newer msi file online and actually calls 'MSIEXEC /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress'. This is the cause of the file being updated. The location of the application is C:/Program Files/MainApplication/

Comment: Can you check to see if there's a %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\MainApplication directory?

Comment: I checked for the directory and it wasn't there. Your question made me think though and exploring the process through the TaskBar - it appears to be executing from a Config.msi directory full of roll back files (.rbf) From this page https://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/19/470980.aspx "the file in question will be renamed and placed in Folder Config.rbf where it will be deleted upon reboot". So it looks like my files are renamed until reboot, which is not too bad.

Comment: That makes some sense... installer can't delete anything, even if it isn't locked, in case you cancel the install at the very last second, it has to be able to put things back.  Still surprised that the renames aren't all happening at reboot too, though, I remembered this as one of the differences between windows and linux (on linux you can unlink a running executable, but you'll get SIGBUS in that process if any of the data was swapped out and later needed).

Answer (score 1):

I guess some caching is happening behind the scene.

Why not sidestep the issue, and just create an empty text document called `restart.txt` and restart if the file exists?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - that's probably what I'll end up doing. I was also curious to know what was going on behind the scene as well.