# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo shows wrong version for a replaced file

Tags: c#, appdomain, system.reflection

Why is it that when a .NET DLL is loaded, replaced from another app domain (DLL is updated with a new version), and then reloaded (using `Assembly.LoadFrom`) that the version info still reflects the old version?

The same is observed with `assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false)` or `assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute), false)`.

Is this the normal behavior? If I inspect the file in Explorer, I see the correct version, though.

Is there any way to get the actual version of the DLL?

Comment: Have you definitely got the updated DLL out of interest? ie any changed method calls, etc. are acting in the new way and not the old way...

Comment: Yes, there are supposed to be changes in the new DLL, but there seem to be none when the DLL is replaced and reloaded.

Restarting the app and reloading the DLL reflects the correct version and functions. So I'm guessing the file version routines mentioned above looks at the remnant copy of the DLL in memory.

Comment: Could be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037365/fileversioninfo-getversioninfo-getting-old-version-of-an-exe-swapped-at-runtime?rq=1)

Comment: I worked around this by temporarily placing the new dll in temp folder then `GetVersionInfo` of that. It actually shows the real version when it's on a different location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't very clear, but the term "re-loaded" is a strong indicator for what you see.  The CLR will not permit reloading a different version of the same assembly with Assembly.LoadFrom().  This is a strong DLL Hell counter measure and avoids a lot of nasty runtime exceptions.  In particular InvalidCastExceptions that say "Cannot cast Foo to Foo".  Type identity in .NET includes the [AssemblyVersion] of an assembly.  Calling Assembly.LoadFrom() will just return a reference to the previously loaded assembly.

Nor is there a way to unload an assembly from an AppDomain.  Only thing you can do is create a *new* AppDomain.

I should not mention Assembly.LoadFile(), it doesn't perform this check, that's major misery.

Answer (score 4):

When you load an assembly into an AppDomain, you cannot unload it. So replacing the file and reloading it in an AppDomain that already loaded the assembly simply does not work (that's by design). You need a new AppDomain to load the replaced assembly.